# border-radius strange outline

Tags: html, css, border

There is any solution to get rid of this outline from an image?

[image: image showing aliased pixels on edge between curved white border and yellowish background]

```css
body {
  background: #000
}

.s {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 8px solid #FFF;
  overflow: hidden
}

.s img {
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class="s">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/v9f1nS2.jpg" />
</div>
```

[View on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x9b4uwk8/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't using border solid for making something like this. You should radius the div class, and add padding. After that you make border-radius for the image too. This is only my personal option but i hope this helping..

```css
body {
 background:#000
}
.s {
 width:200px;
 height:200px;
 border-radius:50%;
 overflow:hidden;
  padding:20px;
  background:#fff;
}
.s img {
 width:100%;
  border-radius:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="s">
 <img src="https://i.imgur.com/v9f1nS2.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice. Even just setting the `background-color` of `.s` to white in the OP's original code seems to help.

Comment: omg...you're correct. I just realized that there is no background in .s, i'm always using padding for bordering like this... is that badway? i'm curious

Comment: Not in my opinion; I like your method. I think the issue is a light border anti-aliased over a dark background.